# Getting A Better Understanding Of Streaming Inserts With BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I understand that there has been a material change relating to the BigQuery streaming API. As I received in a message from the Google cloud team on Thursday, May 14th:

"In 2013, we launched Google BigQuery streaming API, making it easy to analyze large amounts of data quickly. This product was free until January 1, 2015, when we began charging for streaming data into Google BigQuery, based on the number of rows inserted into a BigQuery table. Since then, we’ve learned more about how customers are using Google BigQuery and effective August 12, 2015, we will stop charging for Google BigQuery streaming by the number of rows inserted and instead charge by the number of bytes inserted. New pricing will be $0.01 per 200 MB, with a minimum billing size of 1 KB per row. We've increased the default insert-rate limit from 10,000 rows per second, per table, to 100,000 rows per second, per table. In addition, the row-size limit has increased from 20 KB to 1 MB. These changes will allow customers more flexibility when designing insert strategy, and more accurately reflect the value provided by the streaming insert feature. Additional information on pricing can be found on our pricing page."

Based on this, I have a few important questions:

1. Is there a way to easily view the amount of data in the Cloud Console that is currently being streamed into a client's account. Also, should I expect a separate line being included in the billing table? Asking here as I have looked elsewhere and found no answer. I also see nothing in the current billing table to help (see below). The question is material for this user who is presently pushing many Terrabytes of data through BigQuery on a weekly basis.

[image]

2. I would like clarification on the line which notes "minimum billing size of 1 KB per row." If you pass less than 1KB of data per row into the tables, does this mean that you are NOT charged for any data charges for that row?
3. Finally, is there a quick way to calculate the potential financial impact of the change, or any guidance on the best way to programatically optimize the streaming insert calls to minimize the costs?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: regarding your 1) question, we see StreamingBytes entry on our project in the billing screen, not sure why you don't see it: http://screencast.com/t/MF5Pz8tL

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation and screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the rules, I have to confirm with the team:

- If your rows are less than 1KB each, this would bring the price from $0.01 per 100,000 rows to $0.01 per 200,000 rows - an effective 50% reduction of previous pricing.
- If your rows are exactly 2KB each, you won't see any price change.
- You will only see a price increase if your rows are bigger than 2KB.

More good news: The system won't limit each row to 20KB anymore, and now you can stream up to 1 MB per row.

Comment: The 500 rows per streaming insert limit is kinda annoying lately, you should increase that 10x or 200x times.

Comment: @Pentium10 I'll gladly pass the feedback. More background info through email?

Comment: Recently this was introduced: Maximum rows per request: 500 as seen here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery Before this 10k rows fere fine to send in the same shot. I don't see this move wise.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Felipe! If you find out anything else let me know. As soon as you are confirmed I will click and accept the answer!

Comment: @NathanielPayne yup, confirmed!

Comment: @Pentium10 so there are 2 rationales for the '500 rows per call' limit: On one hand this distributes the load better - each call can be processed by a different server. Also - why stream 10k rows in one call? That might be a better use case for batched loads.

Comment: Excellent Felipe! Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Another required feature for streaming is to pass a projectID to be billed for an insert operation, similar to [query request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query). This would make biiling settings much more flexible.